Mirth serial RS 232 reader
I am trying to read data sent from biomedical equipment with just RS 232 using mirth.
I've been able to use mirth TCP reader for the channel source to read data from an equipment with an Ethernet por. However I can't find serial reader in the mirth channel source for this very equipment with just serial port (RS 232). I saw list of installed extensions in mirth but can't figure out where to check out other extensions or download. Please has anyone found a way around this. Thanks.
